# Two laravel apps interfere on xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, virtualhost

I have two different laravel apps running locally on xampp. I've noticed that if one app makes an API call to the second app than the latter uses the database connection of the first app instead of it's own db connection. Is the second app not bootstraping or does it's connection get's overwritten? Did anyone experienced this?

the error

```
Exception has occurred.PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'front.application_users' doesn't exist
```

So actually what happens is that 'front' prefix is the first app database name making the api call and 'application_users' is the table from the 2'nd app.

I am using virtual hosts, and the apps are under different address.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>

DocumentRoot "D:/projects/piaservice/admin/public"
ServerName admin.pia
ServerAlias admin.pia
<Directory "D:/projects/piaservice/admin/public">
    Options All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
    ReWriteEngine On
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:80>

DocumentRoot 'D:/projects/piaservice/frontend/public'
ServerName front.pia
ServerAlias front.pia
<Directory "D:/projects/piaservice/frontend/public">
    Options All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
    ReWriteEngine On
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This would only happen if you're using database connection pooling and even so should not actually result in one app interfering with another

Comment: somehow it has to do with the config cache. If I run config:clear on the 1'st app and config:cache on the second it works.